# Unable to Toggle json data from getjson query

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to utilize the jQuery dropdown tool to toggle data from a json reponse via getjson.  My data rows remain closed and doesn't respond to the click.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onafetsid/4gK5L/8/).

```
$.getJSON('jsondata', function (data) {
    (function () {
        $.each(data.DataCollections, function (i, user) {
            var i = 0;
            var tblRow = "<dt><h1 title='" + user.metadata.title + "'>" + user.dataCollectionID + "</h1></dt>" + "<sub>" + user.metadata.longDescription + "</sub>";
            tblRow = tblRow + "<dd><ul>"
            while (i < user.data.length) {
                tblRow = tblRow + "<li><i>" + "<b class='gray'>" + user.data[i].id + "</b> - " + user.data[i].alias + "</i></li>"
                i++
            }
            tblRow = tblRow + "</ul></dd>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#DataCollections");
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery("#Facts dd").hide();
                jQuery("#Facts dt").click(function () {
                    jQuery(this).next("#Facts dd").slideToggle(650);
                    jQuery(this).toggleClass("expanded");
                });
            });
        })
    })();
});
```

Comment: what exactly is expected, sorry couldn't understand. Do you need an accordion like behavior (https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) ?

Comment: where is `#Facts` .. not shown in html

Comment: My expected behavior is to toggle between showing the user.data.id and user.data.alias items and hiding them.  It currently hides them.

Comment: Also - #Facts is shown in the fiddle example.  <div id="content"> <dl id="Facts"><div id="DataCollections"></div></dl> </div>